# Запуск сервера Nest js, чтобы выполнить Cron таски

Tags: cron, nestjs, typeorm

Обязательно ли запускать весь сервер Nest чтобы запустить cron таски? Или есть какой-то подход написания launch скрипта в packages.json, который позволяет запустить только связанные с typeorm таски для cron, при этом, не меняя оригинальный код проекта?

Answer (score 0):

Cron таски NestJS можно выполнить только при работающем проекте NestJS. Если у вас есть БД в которой так же указаны timestamp'ы ваших Cron, то можете написать отдельный скрипт, который каждые секунд 10 будет получать все кроны, проходиться по ним и если он находит крону, которая устарела - выполнять её, а после удалять из БД
Либо что-то универсальное, по типу
`"нынешнее время"-"последний запуск кроны" > "интервал"`